# Orientation of left and right translations on a Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, orientation

I read that if $G$ is a connected Lie Group, then for every $g \in G$, the left and right translations ($L_g$ and $R_g$, respectively), preserve orientation. The reason given is that $L_g$ and $R_g$ can be deformed through diffeomorphisms of $G$ to the identity map on $G$.

This last part (tell me if I'm wrong) means that it exists diffeomorphisms $f_i: G \to G (i=1,2)$ such that both
$$f_i \circ L_g: G \to G \text{ and } f_2 \circ R_g: G \to G$$
are the identity map on G. In fact, we can take $f_1 = L_{g^{-1}}$ and $f_2 = R_{g^{-1}}$. From here, it follows that (differentiating and applying the chain rule)
$$(D_{g^{-1}h}L_g) \circ (D_{h} L_{g^-1}) = I$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix of order $\dim G$ (and similarly for $R_g$). Taking the determinant,
$$\det(D_{g^{-1}h}L_g)  \det(D_{h} L_{g^-1}) = 1.$$
I know that, since $L_g$ is a diffeomorphism, it either preserves orientation everywhere or reverses orientation everywhere. From the equation above, it's obvious that $L_g$ and $L_{g^{-1}}$ cannot be such that one preserves and the other reserves the orientation. But how do we know that they both preserve orientation?

**Note**
My definition for left and right translations is the following: for $g \in G$
$$L_g: G \to G, h \mapsto gh \text{ and } R_g: G \to G, h \mapsto hg.$$
(It is not explicit here, but $gh = g \cdot h$ where $\cdot$ is the operation on $G$).

I read that on the 2nd page of

http://www.math.toronto.edu/karshon/grad/2009-10/2010-01-11.pdf

Comment: Note that you have at no points used that $G$ is connected, so this argument *has* to be incomplete. "Deformed through diffeomorphisms" means that there is a smooth map $H\colon G\times I\rightarrow G$ such that $H(-,0)=L_g$, $H(-,1)=\mathrm{id}$ and $H(-,t)\colon G\rightarrow G$ is a diffeomorphism for all $t\in I$ (think of it as a jointly continuous family of diffeomorpisms of $G$ that interpolate between $L_g$ and $\mathrm{id}$). In general, such an $H$ is called a diffeotopy between $H(-,0)$ and $H(-,1)$. The relevant claim is that diffeotopic diffeomorphisms are equioriented.

Comment: Thank you! We didn't talked about this notion of "diffeotopy" in class (just a little of "homotopy" - where instead of diffeomorphism we only have differentiable), but I think I understood what you said. I'm trying to solve an exercise with integrals and a left-invariant volume form, and I would get trouble with $\pm$ if $R_g$ reversed orientation.

Comment: Before you can talk about whether a map preserves orientation or not, you need to define an orientation. The usual way to define an orientation on a Lie group (connected or not) is to choose an orientation on the tangent space at the identity $e$, and then declare the orientation on any other tangent space $T_gG$ to be the one induced by the isomorphism $d(L_g): T_eG\to T_gG$. With this definition, the fact that $L_g$ preserves orientation is more or less immediate, and no deformation argument is required.

Comment: Thank you! That simplifies it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is to expand on Jack Lee's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340136/orientation-of-left-and-right-translations-on-a-lie-group#comment9053321_4340136). It really more or less follows from the (canonical) definition of an orientation of a Lie group.

Given a Lie group and let $\mathcal O_e = [v_1, \cdots, v_n]$ be an orientation on $T_eG$, here $(v_1, \cdots, v_n)$ is an basis of $T_eG$. Then one can define, for each $g\in G$ an orientation $\mathcal O_g$ on $T_gG$ by
$$\mathcal O_g := [ d(L_g)_e v_1, \cdots, d(L_g)_e v_n],$$
where $L_g$ is the left multiplication. Since the mapping
$$ G\times T_eG \to TG, \ \ (g, v) \mapsto d(L_g)_e v$$
is smooth, $\mathcal O$ is an orientation on $G$.

It is easy to check that $L_g$ preserves the orientation $\mathcal O$: for each $h\in G$, using $L_g\circ L_h = L_{gh}$, the equivalence class
$$ \mathcal O_h = [d(L_h)_e v_1, \cdots, d(L_h)_e v_n]$$
is sent to
\begin{align}
[d(L_g)_hd(L_h)_e v_1, \cdots, d(L_g)_hd(L_h)_e v_n] &= [d(L_{gh})_e v_1, \cdots, d(L_{gh})_e v_n] = \mathcal O_{gh}.
\end{align}

Of course, we can replace $(v_1, \cdots, v_n)$ with $(-v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n)$ and construct another orientation $\widetilde {\mathcal O}$ on $G$, and the same argument implies that $L_g$ is orientation preserving with respect to this new orientation.

Now we use connectedness: Since $G$ is connected, $G$ [has exactly two orientations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153451/every-connected-orientable-smooth-manifold-has-exactly-two-orientations-lee-pro). Thus the orientation on $G$ is either $\mathcal O$ or $\widetilde{\mathcal O}$ and wehave shown that $L_g$ is orientation preserving.

The same argument for $R_g$. We can replace $L_g$ with $R_g$ in the above constructions to construct the two orientations on $G$ and show that $R_g$ preserves both orientations. But these two new orientations are exactly $\{ \mathcal O, \widetilde{\mathcal O}\}$ since $G$ has exactly two orientations. Thus $R_g$ is also orientation-preserving with respect to $\mathcal O$ or $\widetilde{\mathcal O}$.

Comment: Thank you! In class, we didn't exactly mentioned orientation on Lie Groups, and I was having trouble understanding certain aspects of it.

Comment: @DianaFerreira Do you know why $G$ is orientable?

Comment: Every Lie group is orientable. I know that every tangent bundle is orientable and every Lie Group is parallelizable, that is, if G is a Lie group with dimension $n$, then the tangent bundle $TG$ is isomorphic to $G \times \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $G$ must be orientable.

Comment: But do you know how to show that every Lie group is orientable? @DianaFerreira

Comment: Yes. I take an atlas on $G$ and construct the appropriate atlas for $TG$, let's say $\{(V_{\alpha},\psi_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha \in I}$. Then I just prove that $D( \psi_{\beta} \circ \psi_{\alpha}^{-1})$ has positive determinant (this matrix has triangular form, with equal diagonal blocks). This proves that $TG$ is orientable. On the other hand, $G \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to $TG$ and thus $G$ is orientable.

Comment: Looks like you mixed up the orientability of $TG$ and that of $G$. Your argument about the (differential of ) transition maps having positive determinant shows that every tangent bundle $TM$ is orientable. But that does not imply that $M$ is orientable. @DianaFerreira (What is your definition of an orientable manifold?)

Comment: If $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha \in I}$ is a differentiable atlas for $M$, then $M$ is orientable if $\det D(\phi_{\beta} \circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}) > 0$ in all points of $U_{\alpha}$, and for all $\alpha,\beta \in I$. It is true that every tangent bundle $TM$ is orientable, and that this does not imply that $M$ is orientable. However, if $G$ is a Lie group, we know that $TG \cong G \times \mathbb{R}^n$, where $n = \dim G$. That's why I conclude that $G$ is orientable ($TG$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are both orientable, and we have an isomorphism...).

Comment: You seem to use that if $M_1\times M_2$ and $M_2$ are orientable, then so is $M_1$. But this is also not true. @DianaFerreira

Comment: Actually, I don't need $M_2$ orientable. $M_1 \times M_2$ is orientable if and only if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are orientable. I've seen a proof for this result. Why do you think this is not true?

Comment: @DianaFerreira Indeed, my previous comment is incorrect.